# Is "banned from the airways" an eggcorn or malapropism?

Tags: eggcorn, malapropisms

It should be "banned from the airwaves", meaning "not allowed to be played on radio".  I noticed this mistake in a British newspaper [story](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2066203/Gary-Glitter-free-travel-year-ban-comes-end.html).

> The former star's music has largely been *banned from the airways* since his fall from grace.

Is this an eggcorn?

Comment: Maybe it means "not allowed to be sung", as in, it's banned from your trachea.

Comment: Or not allowed to be played on planes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an eggcorn according to either of two ways of defining *[airway](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/airway)*: either his songs are not allowed to be sung (*airway* meaning air passage for breathing) or they are not allowed to be played on planes (*airway* meaning plane route).

Comment: The point being: The newspaper meant to say **banned from the airwaves**, meaning "not played on radio".  Mistakenly saying **airways** makes this an eggcorn.  Or maybe just a misprint.